# Is there a way to launch EMR jobs on AWS Virtual Private Cloud.

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-vpc

Is there a way to launch EMR jobs on AWS Virtual Private Cloud. I am planning to launch my AWS Simple workflow which will boot cluster and Add jobs to the clusetr using AWS VPC for some security reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Login to AWS console
2) Goto EMR -> create cluster
3)Under Hardware Configuration you will find Network drop down, here you can select VPC.
IF You have already created VPC it will show in drop down. if its not there you can create VPC , then select it while launching your cluster

Comment: @Sandesh..It was helpfull. I was using AWS SDK and connected to my subnet using .withEc2SubnetId("subnetid"). It was helpful.